# Auto Hotkey mapping ctrl-alt-s to d

Tags: autohotkey

The d key in my laptop is not working. I need to remap the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> key combination to d using auto hotkey. However, the send command doesn't really fit my needs as I want to be able to use that key combination for d in other combinations as well, like <kbd>⊞ win</kbd>+<kbd>+d</kbd>, etc. I could code all such custom shortcuts using the send command, but that does not seem very neat. I've tried using the key remapping syntax as follows:

^!s::d

However that doesn't work. As a side note, ^x::^c works perfectly, but, ^x::c doesn't start mapping the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to the key c.

I wonder why.

I'm looking for a simple way to remap multiple keys to a single one, so that other additional keys pressed with it work as well. This is why the * wildcard doesn't fit my requirements.

Comment: I can't think of any way to avoid explicitly listing those additional combinations like Win-Ctrl-Alt-S that should be mapped to Win-D.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Alt and Ctrl in your alternative for the d-key, you won't be able to use any hotkey that contains ctrl/alt and d.
So my suggestion for you is: Use a single key like F1 as an alternative for your d key. Then just put an asterisk in front of it so that it will even trigger when modifiers like ctrl/win and alt are pressed at the same time and it will work just fine.

```
*F1::d
```